# Angular counter trigger event

Tags: angular, typescript, events, ionic3, counter

Typescript:

```
 countDown;
 counter = 10;
 tick = 1000;    

 this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, this.tick)
  .take(this.counter)
  .map(() => --this.counter)
```

And in HTML:

```
  <div>
    <h1>Time left</h1>
    <h2>{{countDown | async | formatTime}}</h2>
  </div>
```

How can I trigger an event wehen counter hits `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
this.countDown = Observable
  .timer(0, this.tick)
  .take(10)
  .filter(value => value === 0)
  .do(() => {})
```

You can also use this because you used `take`

```
this.countDown = Observable
  .timer(0, this.tick)
  .take(10)
  .map(() => --this.counter)
  .finally(() => {})
```

**EDIT** For version 6 :

```
this.countDown = timer(0, this.tick)
  .pipe(
    take(this.counter),
    map(() => --this.counter),
    finalize(() => /* your event */),
)

this.countDown = timer(0, this.tick)
  .pipe(
    take(this.counter),
    map(() => --this.counter),
    filter(value => value === 0),
    tap(() => /* your event */),
)
```

Comment: I'm getting: `Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
invalidPipeArgumentError@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:42894:12
AsyncPipe.prototype._selectStrategy@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:44343:15
AsyncPipe.prototype._subscribe@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:44325:26
AsyncPipe.prototype.transform@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:44299:17
View_QuizPageLoop_0/<@ng:///AppModule/QuizPageLoop.ngfactory.js:319:40
debugUpdateRenderer@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15109:12...`

Comment: I'm pretty dumb today ... I transformed your observable into a sbuscription. See my edit, should work

Comment: `[ts] Property 'tap' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'.`

Comment: `[ts] Property 'finalize' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'.`

Comment: replace `tap` with `do` and `finalize` with `finally` (this is for RxJS6 and you're not using it).

Comment: `[ts] Property 'finally' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'.`

Comment: `[ts] Property 'do' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'.`

Comment: What version of RX do you have ?

Comment: ` "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",`

Comment: [Seems to work with compat](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pu8w2h), and I edited my answer for RxJS 6

Comment: [Works fine on my side](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e6jzya?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)